# Tem como fazer um for mais simples do que esse?

Tags: c, for

Não estou entendendo esse decremento com o incremento junto.

> Leia 2 inteiros `I`, `F` com `I < F` e conferir se `I` é menor do que o `F`. Imprima `I`, `F`, sucessor de `I`, antecessor de `F`, sucessor do sucessor de `F`, antecessor do antecessor de `F`

Por exemplo, para a entrada `3, 10`, a saída deverá ser:

> ```
> 3, 10, 4, 9, 5, 8, 6, 7.
> ```

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

    int I, F;

    do{
        scanf("%d", &I); /*recebe valor de I*/
        scanf("%d", &F); /*recebe o valor de F*/
    }while (I >= F); /* se I for maior do que F fica no loop*/

    for (int i = I, j= F; i <= j; i++, j--/*Não entendi essa parte*/ /*como saber qual numero pegar ?*/){
        if (i == j){ /*tem como fazer 2 for não?*/
            printf("%d ", i);
        }else{
        printf("%d %d ", i, j);
    }
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("fim de programa\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Sim é possível, não precisa criar variáveis auxiliares e não precisa cuidar da exceção dentro do laço. Daria para eliminar o incremento em uma das variáveis, mas criaria outras necessidades que complicaria o código. Também tem como trocar o `for` por um `while` o que não deixaria de ficar mais simples de alguma forma.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int I, F;
    do {
        scanf("%d", &I);
        scanf("%d", &F);
    } while (I >= F);
    for (; I < F; I++, F--) printf("%d %d ", I, F);
    if (I == F) printf("%d ", I);
    printf("\nfim de programa\n");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CKc9J4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wpkjeenv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Loop/Optimization.c).

Com `while`:

```
while (I < F) printf("%d %d ", I++, F++);
```

Answer (score 2):

Abaixo estarei explicando a sua dúvida em seu código e logo depois estarei fazendo um código para você em cima do seu raciocínio.

> **Seu código:** O **j** no seu código estará recebendo o inteiro **F**. Como você deixou para o usuário fazer o inputs dos dados utilizando o **scanf**, não se saberá com qual valor irá
>   **decrementar(retirar)**, mas supondo que o usuário digitou **10** para o inteiro **F** e **5** para o inteiro **I** o que ocorrerá no
>   **laço(for)** será o seguinte...
>
> - **"i = 5, j = 10; 5 <= 10; i++, j-- "**
>
> **O que este laço(for) significa:** O **contador(i)** inicia-se com **5** e **10** e enquanto o **5 for menor ou igual a 10** ele **somará(incrementará) +1** na **variável** inteira **i** e **tirará(decrementará) 1** na variável inteira **J**. Ele fará isso até sair do laço. Porém este laço está completamente confuso e sem lógica alguma.
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main (){
>
>     int I, F;
>
>     do{
>         scanf("%d", &I); /*recebe valor de I*/
>         scanf("%d", &F); /*recebe o valor de F*/
>     }while (I >= F); /* se I for maior do que F fica no loop*/
>
>     for (int i = I, j= F; i <= j; i++, j--/*Não entendi essa parte*/ /*como saber qual numero pegar ?*/){
>         if (i == j){ /*tem como fazer 2 for não?*/
>             printf("%d ", i);
>         }else{
>         printf("%d %d ", i, j);
>     }
>     }
>
>     printf("\n");
>     printf("fim de programa\n");
>
> return 0;
> }
> ```

**Minha conclusão sobre este laço e variáveis:** Para minha pessoa, o modo que está escrito não está agradável para a manutenção deste código, o que eu faria seria o seguinte:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main (){
>
>     int valorUm, valorDois;
>
>         // Recebe os dois Valores    
>         scanf("%d", &valorUm);
>         scanf("%d", &valorDois);
>
>     do{ 
>         // Armazena os dois valores obtidos nas variáveis auxiliares
>         int auxValorUm = valorUm;
>         int auxValorDois = valorDois;
>
>         // Soma mais 1 na variável inteira auxValorUm
>         // Ex: valorUm = 5; auxValorUm = 5; 5+1 = 6
>         auxValorUm++;
>
>         // Tira 1 na variável inteira auxValorDois
>         // Ex: valorDois = 5; auxValorDois = 5; 5-1 = 4
>         auxValorDois--;
>
>         // O problema aqui é que as variáveis NUNCA serão iguais, pois haverá o incremento e decremento.
>         if(auxValorUm == auxValorDois){
>             printf("%d", auxValorUm);
>             printf("\nFim do Programa");
>             break; // Caso entre neste IF o programa dará a resposta e fechará.
>         }else {
>             printf("%d %d", auxValorUm, auxValorDois);
>             printf("\nFim do Programa");
>             break; // Caso entre neste ELSE o programa dará a resposta e fechará.           
>         }
>     }while(true); // Ocorrerá um LOOP INFINITO, pois a condição é sempre verdadeira.
>
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> **Conclusão do seu Código e Raciocínio Lógico:** Como você pode ver aos
>   meus comentários o seu raciocínio estão errados. **O porque está errado:**
>
> **1)** Você faz um Do-While para gravar diversos valores, porém para você
>   gravar todos esses valores você deve utilizar o vetor para alocar eles
>   na memória.
>
> **2)** O seu IF nunca entrará nele, pois uma variável soma e a outra
>   decrementa.
>
> **3)** Você tem que escrever os nomes das variáveis com as seguintes
>   regras: curto e que se possa entender e camelCase. Você também não
>   pode sair comentando o código, tenha em mente que o comentário tem que
>   ser pouco e em raciocínio que sejam difícil para facilitar o trabalho
>   da manutenção do código, caso outro programador ou até mesmo você
>   venha alterar as linhas de código.

**Observação Importante:** Para que eu possa criar o código corretamente, você precisa editar sua resposta e deixar o enunciado.

Answer (score 1):

Eis o código que você precisa.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int I = 3;
  int F = 10;

  while(I<F){
    printf("%d, %d ", I, F);
    I++;
    F--;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Isso deve computar o que você quer. Se precisar ler os números em tempo de execução, basta usar o `scanf` para ler `I` e `F`.

Comment: Obrigado pela edição e correção, @Rafael Tavares.

Answer (score 0):

As soluções acima se diferenciam do seu código pelo fato de que a maioria delas alteram `I` e `F`, enquanto o seu loop usa variáveis auxiliares `i` e `j` para calcular `I-i` mantendo a informação em `I`. No caso de você querer manter essa informação, uma outra maneira simples de fazer o loop é usar uma única variável auxiliar, já que `i` e `j` sempre tem o mesmo valor:

```
int i=0;
for(; I+i< F-i; i++) printf("%d %d ", I+i, F-i);
if (I+i == F-i) printf("%d", F-i);
```

Você também pode fazer a mesma coisa olhando a diferença entra `I` e `F`:

```
for(int i=0; i<=(F-I)/2; i++)
    if (I+i == F-i) printf("%d", F-i);
    else printf("%d %d ", I+i, F-i);
```